# Response::json() returns text/html as content type

Tags: php, json, apache, laravel-4, content-type

I'm currently facing a strange problem and I cannot narrow down the issue.

In my Laravel application I am retrieving data via AJAX. Therefore parts of the application respond with the `application/json` content-type.

```
return Response::json(['message' => 'Some message']);
```

on my local webserver everything works just fine. I get `Content-Type:application/json` as a response.

I deployed the application on the server (*also apache*) and tested it. But here is the problem. I do not get the proper content-type anymore. Instead I get `text/html`.

So there's a bunch of possible problem sources and I am not too much into server configuration. But here are the things I already tried:

- Made sure that the server has the json extension and it is enabled
- Checked the laravel source for hints why it would not return the proper content/type (I couldn't find anything)
- Checked the response contents locally and on the server (it does not differ)
- I noticed that the Response-Header contains locally `Set-Cookie` which contains: `laravel_session=[...]` whereas the response on the server does not.

*Please refrain from posting  answers that suggest to check for the content-type and parse it if necessary on the client side, because although that would be possible, the server should not behave like that and I'm trying to figure out why*

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?? I'm having the exact same issue. The strange thing is I have other laravel applications in my server and they run just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I ended up parsing it as json client-side

Answer (score 1):

This does sound more like a server configuration problem, especially since it's working fine on your local environment on not on your production environment. I know you made sure that  the server has the json extension and it is enabled, but you might want to double check the following on your production server anyway:

- Do you have the `AddType application/json .json` directive in you Apache configuration (at `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf`)?
- Do you have mod `mime` enabled (can be done via `a2enmod mime`)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I cannot check that because the production server is a managed hosting server. But what I did was to setup a little script where I set the correct json header and returned some json data. It worked fine and I also got `application/json`

Comment: @thpl, can you share the script & details?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answer comes to late but yesterday I ran into this problem and actually kind of solved it. I don't really know why this happens but I noticed that whenever I ran `artisan serve` or any other artisan command a strange tab appeared before all the command messages. So a open all of my controllers and found that there was a tab before a `php` opening tab. So I had something like this:

```
    <?
class MyController extends BaseController{
....
}
```

That tab was there by accident but seems it was causing the problem. As soon as I removed it the `Content-Type` returned by all of my `Response::json` calls returned to be `application/json`

Hope this helps even if it is too late.